# How to compose select request using many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

I have this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, number_of_things int
);

CREATE TABLE things (
  thing_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, cost int
);

CREATE TABLE orders_to_things (
  order_id int REFERENCES orders (order_id)
, thing_id int REFERENCES things (thing_id)
);
```

How to compose a request for select all orders where cost of things more than some number?
I tried to use:

```
SELECT orders.order_id 
FROM orders 
  INNER JOIN orders_to_things ON (orders_to_things.order_id = orders.order_id)  
  JOIN things ON (orders_to_things.thing_id=things.thing_id) 
WHERE (select SUM(things.cost) FROM things) > *some number*
```

but didn't get the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT O.order_id, sum(T.cost)
FROM orders O
INNER JOIN orders_to_things ON orders_to_things.order_id = orders.order_id  
JOIN things T ON orders_to_things.thing_id=things.thing_id 
GROUP BY O.order_id
HAVING T.cost > 'number....'
```

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: @vbif212 if this was helpful then please upvote too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all order ids, you don't need the `orders` table.  The simplest way to write the query is:

```
SELECT ott.order_id, sum(t.cost)
FROM orders_to_things ott JOIN 
     things t
     ON ott.thing_id = t.thing_id 
GROUP BY ott.order_id
HAVING sum(t.cost) > <number>;
```